# Get meta value based on user id

Tags: meta-value

I need to get the meta value based on user id. Such as, I have meta_key called event_comments and the meta_value for this will be set to either Yes or No. I need to get that for the current user id. What I am trying is below.

```
$args = array(
    'user_id' => $postedby, // $postedby is the user id
    'meta_key' => 'event_comments',
    'meta_value' => 'Yes',
);
$getuser = get_users($args);
```

Comment: Are you looking for [`get_user_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_meta/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get_users` is for retrieving users, not meta.

To get the user meta of a user where `$user_id` is that users ID, you can use [`get_user_meta`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_meta/) and it should work the same as the other meta functions:

```php
$meta_value = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'the meta key', true );
```

You can use `$user_id = get_current_user_id();` to retrieve the ID of the currently logged in user, make sure to check that the user is logged in first though.

Comment: That did it. Thanks for the reply.